# omit contol from the tabbing order

Tags: winforms, button, compact-framework, tab-ordering

There are Windows Form with some text controls and button. User with TAB and Enter can focus next element. Button should be skipped.

How can I omit Windows Forms Control (OpennetCF Button2) from the tabbing order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just set its TabStop property to false

```
button1.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: @mishik What are you talking about? I answered his question. You set the TabStop property to false

Comment: Now better, as it was - it was just a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Please not that for invisible controls TabStop must be set in false also!

Comment: If you forget to do this -> the invisible control can be "focused" also. User (and me too) will be confused